# password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php

Getting this error during attempt to login to member account:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\e_id\login.php:77
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\e_id\login.php(77): password_verify('password', NULL)
>   #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\e_id\login.php on line 77

```
<?php

/*
ERROR HANDLING
*/
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

include 'config.php';

// check if user is already logged in
if (is_logged() === true) 
    {
        //Redirect user to homepage page after 5 seconds.
        header("refresh:2;url=home.php");
        exit;
    }


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    { 
        if (isset($_POST["login_username_or_email"]) && 
        isset($_POST["login_password"]))
        {
            $username_or_email = trim($_POST["login_username_or_email"]);
            $password = $_POST["login_password"];
            $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            //Select Username or Email to check against Mysql DB if they are 
            already registered or not.
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT usernames, emails FROM 
            users WHERE usernames = ? OR emails = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, 
            $email_confirmation);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            */

            if(strpos("$username_or_email", "@") === true)
            {
                    $email = $username_or_email;
                    $username = "";
                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT emails FROM users 
                    WHERE emails = ?");                     
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
            }
            else
            {
                    $username = $username_or_email;
                    $email = "";
                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT usernames FROM 
                    users WHERE usernames = ?");
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $username);                  
            }               
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt); 

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            printf("%s (%s)\n",$row["usernames"],$row["passwords"]);
            var_dump($row);

            // Check if inputted Username or Email is registered or not.

            if (!$result) // either this paragraph or ...
            {
                    echo Incorrect User Credentials!";
                    exit;                           
            }
            elseif (password_verify($password, $row['passwords']))
            {
                    if($row['accounts_activations_statuses'] == '0')
                    {
                            echo "You have not activated your 
                            account yet! Check your email for instructions 
                            .";
                            exit;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    //If 'Remember Me' check box is checked then set the 
                    cookie. 
                    //if (isset($_POST['login_remember']) && 
                    $_post['login_remember'] == "on")
                    {
                            setcookie("login_username", $username, time()+ 
                            (10*365*24*60*60));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            //If Cookie is available then use it to auto log 
                            user into his/her account!
                            if (isset($_COOKIE['login_username']))
                            {
                                    setcookie("login_username","","");
                            }
                    }
            $_SESSION["user"] = $username;
            header("location:home.php?user=$username");                             
            }                       
        }
    }

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php $site_name?> Member Login Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<form method="post" action="">
<center><h3><?php $site_name ?> Member Login Form</h3></center>
<div class="text-danger">
<div class="form-group">
<center><label>Username/Email:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="login_username_or_email" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["login_username_or_email"])) echo $_COOKIE["login_username_or_email"]; ?>"</center>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<center><label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="login_password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["login_password"])) echo $_COOKIE["login_password"]; ?>"></center>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<center><label>Remember Login Details:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="login_remember" /></center>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<center><input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Login" class="button button-success" /></center>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<center><font color="red" size="3"><b>Forgot your password ?</b><br><a href="login_password_reset.php">Reset it here!</a></font></center>
<center><font color="red" size="3"><b>Not registered ?</b><br><a href="register.php">Register here!</a></font></center>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error near `echo Incorrect User Credentials!";`. And HTML isn't relevant to this question and may as well be edited out.

Comment: Thank you. I do not have this error in my notepad++ file but I do see I have it in my post. Must have deleted it by accident when manually doing all those 4 spaces on each line to represent the indentations.
Anyway, can you give feed-back with sample snippets on how to improve any area you deem could be improved ?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all the syntax shenanigans, you're not returning the password from the query:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "
  SELECT usernames FROM users WHERE usernames = ?"
);
```

So it will be `null`

Comment: Is not the line like thi:
"$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT usernames, emails FROM 
            users WHERE usernames = ? OR emails = ?");" ?
And that still would yield zero results ? Ok. Then how do you suggest I should have done it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch password column also from db

```
        if(strpos("$username_or_email", "@") === true)
        {
                $email = $username_or_email;
                $username = "";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT emails,passwords FROM users 
                WHERE emails = ?"); //<---Add passwords in select                  
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
        }
        else
        {
                $username = $username_or_email;
                $email = "";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT usernames,passwords FROM 
                users WHERE usernames = ?"); //<---Add passwords in select
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $username);                  
        }
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for bringing my mistake to my attention!

Comment: I switched this:
password_verify($password, $row['passwords']);
To this:
password_verify($password, (string)$row['passwords']);

And this error is gone:
"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\e_id\login.php:77
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\e_id\login.php(77): password_verify('password', NULL)
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\e_id\login.php on line 77".

But should the code really be like that by Type Casting the password_verify 2nd param ?